# Rails not showing error on form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working in rails 2, I have a form containing data of two models, In one model I am validating fields and entering error using `self.errors.add_to_base` , but this is not displaying error on form and submitting that request successfully.

This is my Model validation\

```
validate :checkPunchingEntries

  def checkPunchingEntries
    if self.punch_in_time.blank? && self.punch_out_time.blank?
      self.errors.add_to_base("Both 'Punch in' and 'Punch out' time can not be blank")
    end
  end
```

This is my Form

```
<% form_tag '/punching_requests/create', :method => :post, :class=>"punching_request_form" do %>
    <% @punching_request.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <p class="error"><%=msg%></p>
    <% end %>

    <p>
      <label>Date </label>
      <%= text_field_tag 'date'%>  <%= calendar_for("date") %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <label>&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="punch_in_toggle()">Punch In</input>
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="punch_out_toggle()">Punch Out</input>
    </p>

    <div id="punch_in">
      <p>
        <label>Punch In Time </label>
        <%= text_field_tag 'punch_in_time'%>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="punch_out">
      <p>
        <label>Punch Out Time </label>
        <%= text_field_tag 'punch_out_time'%>
      </p>
    </div>

    <p>
      <label>Assign To</label>
      <%= select_tag(:approved_by,  options_from_collection_for_select(@human_resource_persons, "id", "login")) %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <label>Reason </label>
      <%=text_area_tag 'reason'%>
    </p>

    <p class="actions"><label></label><%= submit_tag 'Save' %></p>

<% end %>
```

It comes into validation, but error is not shown on validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the IRB console? If not, take a look what is going on there, just to be sure, that `@punching_request.errors` contains something.

Answer (score 0):

In this you're generating the form using `form_tag` and the errors you're expecting would be stored in the form builder,`form_for`.

Instead of `form_tag` use `form_for(@punching_request)`. This should do the trick.

Comment: My form contains data related to two model, how can I use form_for in this scenario?

Comment: have a look at the virtual attributes on Railscasts or you can also consider using :accepts_nested_attributes_for..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def checkPunchingEntries
  if self.punch_in_time.blank? && self.punch_out_time.blank?
    errors[:base]<< "Both 'Punch in' and 'Punch out' time can not be blank"
  end
end
```

and use `form_for` and `@punching_request`

**for example**

```
# in your controller
def new
  @punching_request = PunchingRequest.new
end
def create
  ...
  ...
end
```

your form look like in your `new.html.erb`

```
form_for(@punching_request)
  ...
  ...
end
```

Comment: My form contains data related to two model, how can i use form_for in this scenario?